# How to configure an alias in Apache 2.4?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I need to config an alias in Apache 2.4, and work the same as phpmyadmin works in my Ubuntu AWS server. I created a site-enable file and add the following lines for it

```
    Alias /admin1/ "/var/www/html/admin"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/admin">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

But when I hit /admin1 it redirects to the 404 page,

Comment: Check Apache error logs and update in your question

Comment: I got this from access.log file

**123.231.16.77 - - [09/Jun/2014:07:17:19 +0000] "GET /admin1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/30.0.1599.114 Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36"
123.231.16.77 - - [09/Jun/2014:07:17:25 +0000] "GET /admin1 HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/30.0.1599.114 Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36"**

Comment: have you restarted webserver after updating configuration ? but before restart do config test using `apachectl -t`

Comment: yes I did and i restart the server still its not good. and also after running `apachectl -t` I get  Syntax OK message

Comment: once check with `Alias /admin1 "/var/www/html/admin"`, and also remove allow,deny order instead, you need to use `Require all granted` Ref https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: I tried that still no good, and now my virtual host like this

        `Alias /admin1 "/var/www/admin.dgstg2.com/html"
        <Directory "/var/www/admin.dgstg2.com/html">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>`

Comment: Try location instead of alias for me worked fine.

Comment: Did you configure a `DirectoryIndex` pointing to index.php or index.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and my fix was to make sure my file ended with `.conf` .  It seems this wasn't required in apache 2.2.

**EDIT**

As per the comment, apache 2.4's apache2.conf contains this line: `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` .  `sites-available` isn't related to this, unless you've got a symlink from `sites-enabled`.

Comment: This might be right, for sites-enabled they do need to end with .conf. Have an upvote for remembering that change. Note that they don't need it in sites-available, just the symbolic link name in sites-enabled need it. Same goes for all the xxx-enabled files, which are actually all symbolic links to their respective xxx-available files, which can be named anything.